# Vba Web Navigation and authentication

Tags: html, excel, vba

```
Sub HTML_Element_Printer()

On Error GoTo Err_Clear
sURL = "https://ernie.erau.edu/"
Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer
oBrowser.Silent = True
oBrowser.timeout = 60
oBrowser.navigate sURL
oBrowser.Visible = True

Do
' Wait till the Browser is loaded
Loop Until oBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set HTMLDoc = oBrowser.document

HTMLDoc.all.loginID.Value = "User123"
HTMLDoc.all.Password.Value = "Pass123"

For Each oHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
Debug.Print oHTML_Element.Name
Next

' oBrowser.Refresh ' Refresh If Needed
Err_Clear:
If Err <> 0 Then
Err.Clear
Resume Next
End If

End Sub
```

I am trying to use vba to navigate through multiple websites and login to it respectively, thus, i am using my school portal as a trial for now. The code seems to work successfully in navigating to the site, but i can't input the user and password i want. It is the first time i am using vba to do web navigation and user authentication, i was hoping to find some help and advice here. Thanks.

Comment: Exactly how does it fail?

Comment: It doesn't input the user name and password. It is just a simple program whereby user can click the macro and it will login and bring user into the site.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the error handling?

Comment: Yes sir, it still doesn't work.

Comment: And no error messages?

Comment: There were no error messages. When i ran the code, it only manages to open up the web page. It doesn't input any information like user name and password that is required to access

Comment: And no debug output?

Comment: I get redirected to https://fed.erau.edu/oamfed/idp/samlv20   . Can that url be used also?

Comment: No Sir, i've tried a few methods and it brought me to the same page as well.